# seperate CKServerChangeTokens for the privateCloudDatabase and the sharedCloudDatabase?

Tags: ios, ios10, cloudkit

I am trying to implement CKShare in iOS 10 CloudKit.

Do I need to keep track of seperate CKServerChangeTokens for the privateCloudDatabase and the sharedCloudDatabase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `CKServerChangeToken` is used with various database operations, and those operations are called on a specific CloudKit database, then yes, you need to keep track of database specific tokens.